# How can I improve my java code to make it dynamic? if message chunks are in double or triple digit for that matter

Tags: java

> Given a char limit split message into meaningful chunks without splitting words.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class splitMessage {

    static ArrayList<String> splitText(String message, int charLimit) {

        return splitTextAuxUsingSplit(message, charLimit);
    }

    static ArrayList<String> splitTextAuxUsingSplit(String message, int charLimitOriginal) {
        // Decrease the char limit to accomodate chunk number at the end i.e. (1/3). For
        // **now assuming, the message chunks won't be more than 9** //what if //message chunks are in double or triple digit? how do I improvise?
        int charLimit = charLimitOriginal - 7;
        // New arraylist to store message chunks
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] splitted = message.split(" ");
        String temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length - 1; i++) {
            temp = splitted[i];
            // while length of temp and the next element combined is less than charLimit,
            // temp = temp + next element
            // Last element to be taken care of after this loop
            while ((temp + 1 + splitted[i + 1]).length() <= charLimit && i + 1 < splitted.length - 1) { // +1 for space
                temp = temp + " " + splitted[i + 1];
                i++;
            }
            result.add(temp);

        }
        // Take care of the last element
        // Add the last element from splitted to the last element of result if their
        // combined length is less than charLimit
        String lastElement = result.get(result.size() - 1);
        if (lastElement.length() + 1 + splitted[splitted.length - 1].length() < charLimit) { // +1 for space

            result.set(result.size() - 1, lastElement + " " + splitted[splitted.length - 1]);
        } else {
            result.add(splitted[splitted.length - 1]);
        }

        // append message chunk number for ex (1/3)
        int resultSize = result.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSize; i++) {
            result.set(i, "[" + (i + 1) + "/" + resultSize + "]: " + result.get(i));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message;
        int charLmit;
        message = "Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now! And this is a bigger text. Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now! And this is a bigger text. Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now! And this is a bigger text Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now! And this is a bigger text ";
        charLmit = 25;
        ArrayList<String> result = splitText(message, charLmit);
        for (String item: result) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }

    }
}
```

How do I improvise this code so that it gives correct output even for 2,3 digit message chunks like [1/300] or [29/35]

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is, or what you're really asking. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This task does not have a very effective solution, you just need to try different chunk sizes in a loop. You initially assume that the text can be split in no more than 9 chunks, so the information text will be just 7 characters long, e.g. `"[1/9]: "`. You perform the actual split of the text into chunks of length `charLimit - 7`. If you get no more than 9 chunks after that - all good. If not, then you need to assume that the text can be split in no more than 99 chunks. The information text will be 9 characters long now, e.g. `"[12/99]: "`. So you try splitting the text into chunks of length `charlimit - 9`. If you get less than 100 chunks - all good. If not - you again increase the maximum to 1000 and information text size by 2 and repeat the process until you find the solution.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SplitMessage {

    static List<String> splitWordsToLimit(String[] words, int charLimit) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        int wordsOnThisLine = 0;
        for (String word : words) {
            if (wordsOnThisLine == 0 || 
               (line.length() + 1 + word.length() <= charLimit)) {
                    if (wordsOnThisLine != 0) {
                       line.append(" ");
                    }
                    line.append(word);
                    wordsOnThisLine++;
               } else {
                    result.add(line.toString());
                    wordsOnThisLine = 1;
                    line = new StringBuilder(word);
               }               
        }
        if (wordsOnThisLine != 0) {
                result.add(line.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    static List<String> splitText(String message, int charLimit) {      
        String[] words = message.split(" ");
        int maxChunks = 10;
        int infoSize = "[1/9]: ".length();
        List<String> chunks;
        while (true) {
            chunks = splitWordsToLimit(words, charLimit - infoSize);
            if (chunks.size() < maxChunks && charLimit > infoSize + 1) {
                break;
            }
            maxChunks *= 10;
            infoSize += 2;
        }
        int digits = String.valueOf(chunks.size()).length();
        String infoFormat = "[%" + String.valueOf(digits) + "d/" + 
                             String.valueOf(chunks.size()) + "]: ";
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
            result.add(String.format(infoFormat, i + 1) + chunks.get(i));
        }
        return result;
    }
        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message;
        int charLimit;
        message = "Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now! And this is a bigger text. Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now! And this is a bigger text. Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now! And this is a bigger text Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now! And this is a bigger text ";
        charLimit = 25;
        List<String> result = splitText(message, charLimit);
        for (String item: result) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Output for `charLimit = 50`:

```
[1/7]: Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now!
[2/7]: And this is a bigger text. Hi Sivasrinivas,
[3/7]: your Uber is arriving now! And this is a
[4/7]: bigger text. Hi Sivasrinivas, your Uber is
[5/7]: arriving now! And this is a bigger text Hi
[6/7]: Sivasrinivas, your Uber is arriving now!
[7/7]: And this is a bigger text
```

Output for `charLimit = 25`:

```
[ 1/20]: Hi Sivasrinivas,
[ 2/20]: your Uber is
[ 3/20]: arriving now!
[ 4/20]: And this is a
[ 5/20]: bigger text. Hi
[ 6/20]: Sivasrinivas,
[ 7/20]: your Uber is
[ 8/20]: arriving now!
[ 9/20]: And this is a
[10/20]: bigger text. Hi
[11/20]: Sivasrinivas,
[12/20]: your Uber is
[13/20]: arriving now!
[14/20]: And this is a
[15/20]: bigger text Hi
[16/20]: Sivasrinivas,
[17/20]: your Uber is
[18/20]: arriving now!
[19/20]: And this is a
[20/20]: bigger text
```